# How to get only top 1 row from second table in SQL Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Join two tables where table1 contains only 1 record and table2 contains multiple records of same ID but different serials. Join is on wkid but i want to get only max serial from table2

```
SELECT
        t1.wkid
    ,   t1.ser
    ,   t2.nama
    ,   t1.comments
FROM
        table1 t1
    ,   table2 t2
WHERE
        t1.wkid = t2.wkid
    AND t2.ser = MAX(ser)
```

Table creation and inserts:

```
create table table1(wkid int, ser int, comments text);
insert into table1 values(721142, 1, 'asdfasd');
insert into table1 values(721142, 2, 'vnivnie');
insert into table1 values(721142, 3, 'el;eklke');
insert into table1 values(721142, 4, 'fefeo');
insert into table1 values(721142, 5, 'jijie');
insert into table1 values(721143, 1, 'my comments 1');
insert into table1 values(721143, 2, 'my comments 2');
insert into table1 values(721143, 3, 'my comments 3');

create table table2(wkid int, nama text);
insert into table2 values(721142, 'John');
insert into table2 values(721143, 'Andy');
insert into table2 values(721144, 'Khan');
insert into table2 values(721145, 'Jack');
```

Expected result:

```
721142 | 5 | John | jijie
721143 | 3 | Andy | my comments 3
```

Comment: Start by using explicit `join` syntax; implicit, comma separated join style is out of date for nearly 30 years.

Comment: Please avoid posting images of data, the users here can't use them without transcribing them. Please take the time to either post data as formatted `text`, or even better as DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31730d7d75472f9c3f2d5b9be755570d)**

```
select * from 
(
select t1.wkid, t1.ser, t2.nama, t1.comments, row_number() over(partition by t1.wkid order by ser desc) as rn 
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.wkid = t2.wkid
)A where rn=1
```

OUTPUT:

```
wkid    ser nama    comments       rn
721142  5   John    jijie           1
721143  3   Andy    my comments 3   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicit JOIN

```
SELECT A.wkid, A.ser, B.nama, A.comments
    FROM table1 A, table2 B
    WHERE B.wkid = A.wkid
        AND A.ser = (SELECT max(X.ser) FROM table1 X
                        WHERE X.wkid = A.wkid)
```

Explicit JOIN

```
SELECT A.wkid, A.ser, B.nama, A.comments
    FROM table1 A JOIN table2 B
    ON B.wkid = A.wkid
    WHERE A.ser = (SELECT max(X.ser) FROM table1 X
                        WHERE X.wkid = A.wkid)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

In this case, ironically though, possibly the best solution uses `APPLY` and not `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.wkid, t2.ser, t2.nama, t1.comments
FROM table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) t2.*
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t1.wkid = t2.wkid
      ORDER BY t2.ser DESC
     ) t2;
```

This should effectively use an index on `table2(wkid, ser desc)`.

Comment: _t2.ser?_ table2 is (wkid, nama)